# Uso e significato della costruzione "salvo" + infinito

Tags: word-usage, meaning, prepositions

Su una guida turistica di Riga ho letto questa frase in riferimento alla cattedrale ortodossa:

> Costruita alla fine del XIX secolo, questa chiesa in mattoni gialli venne convertita in planetario durante l'occupazione, **salvo tornare** alla sua funzione originaria nel 1990, seppur con gran parte dei suoi ornamenti andati distrutti.

Non riesco a capire qual è il ruolo di "salvo" in un costrutto del tipo "salvo" + infinito come quello che appare nel brano sopra citato. Ne ho trovato un altro esempio sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI23/GDLI_Supplemento_2004_787.pdf&parola=salvo):

> Cara Tina, gra­zie  di  tutto,  anche  da  parte  di  Anselm,  che  in  questo  momento  sog­giorna  al  Kaiserin  Hotel  di  Feldafing,  in  Baviera,  presso  il  Lago  di Stamberg,  dove  riposa,  fa  lunghe  passeggiate  nei  boschi  e  di  tanto  in tanto  gioca  a  golf,  **salvo  poi  recuperare**  i  grammi  persi  nel  ristorante dell’hotel  stesso,  gestito  dal  bravo  e  gentile  Herr  Tino  (lo  giuro,  Tina, 
>   Herr  Tino  a  Feldafing  esiste  davvero,  e  da  lui  si  mangia  la  Wiener Schnitzel migliore del mondo).

Ho cercato alla [voce "salvo" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/salvo) (l'entrata "salvo" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* non si legge bene), ma non ho trovato nessuna spiegazione su questa struttura.

Potreste spiegarmi qual è il senso e come si usa "salvo" in construzioni del tipo "salvo" + infinito?

Comment: È lo stesso di “per poi (tuttavia)”. Non bellissimo, secondo me.

Answer (score 2):

Nel caso del periodo costruito sopra, l'accezione del termine "salvo" implica una restrizione, o la fine di una condizione reggente o principale.

"Salvo tornare..." nel periodo implica che fino al verificarsi dell'evento "*raggiungere l'anno 1990*" la funzione era la precedente. 
La chiesa era stata trasformata in planetario **fino a che**, nel 1990, è stata riportata alla precedente funzione di chiesa.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Quindi, il ruolo e il significato di "salvo" sarebbero diversi nella prima e nella seconda frase della domanda?

Comment: Grazie del benvenuto! :D

Comment: Sostanzialmente il significato è identico, nel secondo caso la sottigliezza sta nel fatto che "salvo poi" indica la fine della condizione. La passeggiata ha consentito di perdere grammi (di grasso), ma il pranzo al ristorante fa terminare il vantaggio portato dalla passeggiata.

Comment: Quindi, "salvo" +  "verbo all'infinito" può semplicemente significare "fino a quando" + "verbo in passato"? Nell'esempio della domanda, "salvo tornare alla sua funzione originaria" sarebbe lo stesso che "fino a quando tornò alla sua funzione originaria".

Comment: Ho trovato un altro esempio su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=xsc6CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq=%22salvo+poi+ritornare%22&source=bl&ots=GTn1wckVN3&sig=ACfU3U3M0XdCT5Kplbv5EktaBUNhStKAYg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH2ZfP9d7jAhUHAGMBHZQhBb4Q6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22salvo%20poi%20ritornare%22&f=false): "Lucas fece per inseguirla, **salvo poi ritornar** immediatamente sui propri passi". Significherebbe "Lucas fece per inseguirla **fino a quando** ritornò immediatamente sui propri passi"?

Comment: Tuttavia, mi sa che si perde qualche sfumatura di "fare qualcosa al contrario".

Comment: È uno dei sensi possibili. Ecco un articolo interessante dell'Accademia della Crusca italiana  [link](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/salvo)

Comment: Grazie, @ChristianL., l'avevo già letto. Questo articolo fa questa spiegazione su uno degli usi di "salvo": "introduce una proposizione eccettuativa o limitativa, la quale contiene cioè «una restrizione, un condizionamento rispetto alla reggente»", ma quando si tratta di "salvo" + infinito, questa proposizione è implicita". Ma non riesco a capire cosa significa.

Comment: Nel caso del brano "Lucas fece...." il significato è un cambio di atteggiamento. Il personaggio fece (iniziò) per inseguirla, ma ad un certo punto cambiò idea (il _salvo_ in questo caso indica la fine della sua intenzione iniziale) e tornò sui suoi passi.